# How to get the discussion part in Devops (Analytics Views) for we can export to power BI

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I created different analytics views for export work items in DevOps but when try to see with it's the correct field for export the discussion  section , I don't see it only see the Comment Count.

This only count the comments quantity by work item, could you help me to explain if exist one form to export this section from DevOps and put on Power BI (throught Analytics Views)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Sem.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this time, however, it is not supported to get comment content through Analytics view.

The Analytics service doesn't store any data for long text fields assigned the HTML or rich text data type, such as comments, description and history. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-fields-reference?view=azure-devops).